# Finding the domain of a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus

I have to find the domain of the function: $$\ln(\ln(2^x-x)) $$The conditions I get are $x \gt 0$ and $\ln(2^x-x) \gt 0$

But then I don't know how to get the interval for x.

Thanks

Comment: Solving $\ln(2^x-x) \gt 0$, i.e. $2^x-x>1$, note that equality holds for $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the function on the LHS is strictly convex. Are you sure that $x>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need $\ln(2^x-x) >0$.

$\text{Hint}$:

Remember that $\ln(v) > 0$ if $v>1$ (if this is not clear, see the graph of $\ln x$). Then for $\ln(2^x-x)>0$ you need $2^x-x>1 \iff 2^x>1+x$. Can you solve, or at least get an intuition for, this inequality?

$\text{Solution:}$

> $$2^x > 1+x$$

> is true for $x>1$ and $x<0$. Then the domain is $x\in(-\infty, 0) \cup(1, \infty)$ If the reason for this is not clear, consider what happens to the LHS when $x$ is a fraction.

Comment: Thank you all clear now.  I think generally I have troubles with logarithm functions. For example (ln(x))^2-x>0  is very hard for me. Looking at the graph I can see that it is true for values of x close to zero and smaller than 0.5 but I dont know how to calculate it.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer as correct so that the post does not linger in the unanswered section. In what comes to the second problem you mention, an instant intuition is to perform the substitution $u=\ln x \implies x = e^u$. Then the inequality $\ln^2 x > x$ becomes $u^2 > e^u$, which seems at first hand more approachable. However, I haven't worked this out in any detail, it's just a place to start for  you.